# Does extend operator support whitespace when specify a new column name?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When I want to generate a new column name with extend, and the new column name contains a white space, code like below:

```
requests 
| extend "users name" = ""
//other codes
```

then an error occurs: Query could not be parsed at '=' on line xxx.
So the question is that can we use white space in the new column name with extend?

I also tried use single quote, still the same error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use the square brackets:

datatable(['a b']:string)["this works"]

See more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/schema-entities/entity-names

Comment: Perfect, just searching for this.